# "Dash plotly": I face a problem in connecting two inputs to an output also the bas x axis is not sorted and correctly categorized

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

This is the custom function which is 100% wrong. what is the correct code to filter the graph according to two different inputs?

```
app.layout = html.Div([
html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H3('Select a Country'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'drop',
options =[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df["Country"].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'All'}], 
value='All')
    ],style={'width': '35%','display':'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
        html.H3('Select a Reason'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'drop1',
options =[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df["Source"].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'All'}], 
value='All')
    ],style={'width': '35%','display':'inline-block'}),
], className="row"),
  html.Div(dcc.Graph(
 id = "graph"))
],style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block'})

@app.callback(Output('graph','figure'),
          [Input('drop', 'value'),Input('drop1', 'value')])
          



def update_graph(country,reason):
if (country == 'value') | (reason == 'value'):
    dff=df

else:
    
    dff = df[(df['Country']==country) &
            (df['Source']==reason)]


fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=dff["Week"], y=dff["Source"].value_counts())]) 
      
fig.update_layout(barmode='relative', title_text='Number of Orders')
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
return fig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated your data frame
- you have logic bombs rather than structural issues

  1. `if (country == 'All') or (reason == 'All'):` conditional logic for **callback** data frame filtering
  2. figure creation,  made no sense so replaced

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

S = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":np.random.choice(["UK","US"], S), "Source":np.random.choice(list("ABC"), S),
                  "Date":pd.date_range("1-jan-2021",freq="D",periods=S)}).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Week=d["Date"].dt.week))

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H3("Select a Country"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="drop",
                            options=[
                                {"label": i, "value": i} for i in df["Country"].unique()
                            ]
                            + [{"label": "Select all", "value": "All"}],
                            value="All",
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "35%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H3("Select a Reason"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="drop1",
                            options=[
                                {"label": i, "value": i} for i in df["Source"].unique()
                            ]
                            + [{"label": "Select all", "value": "All"}],
                            value="All",
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "35%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
            ],
            className="row",
        ),
        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id="graph")),
    ],
    style={"width": "100%", "display": "inline-block"},
)

@app.callback(Output('graph','figure'),
          [Input('drop', 'value'),Input('drop1', 'value')])
def update_graph(country,reason):
    if (country == 'All') or (reason == 'All'):
        dff=df
    else:
        dff = df[(df['Country']==country) &
            (df['Source']==reason)]

    dff = dff.drop(columns=["Date"]).value_counts().reset_index()
    fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=dff["Week"], y=dff[0])])
#     fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=dff["Week"], y=dff["Source"].value_counts())])

    fig.update_layout(barmode='relative', title_text='Number of Orders')
    fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
    return fig

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: Thank you very much it really had supported me but if you could explain the filtered data frame, regarding this line dff = dff.drop(columns=["Date"]).value_counts().reset_index()
and the y axis from the figure,
also if you know the trick to make each of the two drop downs dynamically interacting  solo (single input) as we have to select from both of them simultaneously to update the figure, and i need to update the figure if i selected from one dropdown only by it self and if i select the other dropdown list will update simultaneously too as it is
thank you again sir.

Comment: you code had logic and coding bombs.  both x & y parameters should be arrays of the same length.  what you coded could not do that... hence `dff = dff.drop(columns=["Date"]).value_counts().reset_index()` to get counts of rows without considering the date, just the country and source.  this returns a multi-index pandas series, convert it back into a data frame so it's simple to pick out x and y values.  if you look at `dff` you will see column **0** are the counts, I didn't bother to rename it to a more meaningful column name